# Linux testing - CPU & disk

Tags: linux, central-processing-unit, load-testing, performance

I am a bit rusty lately. What is the standard way to test CPU and disk I/O these days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One test I do is compile the kernel. Maybe prime. Also I'm refering to this list quite a lot lately as I am testing a lot of VM configurations.

http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=486495

As for "standard", I'm not sure there is one. What I think you might want to do is create a set of tests that are standard for you and apply that to your variations.

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools out there that perform stress testing.

For Linux a easy to use one is stress: http://weather.ou.edu/~apw/projects/stress/

Answer (score 1):

for the disk: [bonnie++](http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/). not your most trendy benchmarking tool but one that gives useful results [ random and sequential reads/writes, i/o per sec ].

Answer (score 0):

I still continue to use the old^H^H^Hclassic standbys for disk performance testing:  [Iozone](http://www.iozone.org/) and [iometer](http://www.iometer.org).  Iozone is fairly easy to get going, while Iometer can be configured to more closely match your real-life load characteristics (assuming you know what they are, of course).  I believe both are available on multiple platforms, including Linux and Windows.